# Is there a way to apply a velocity.js animation over a NodeList?

Tags: javascript, velocity.js, nodelist

Is there a way to apply a velocity.js animation over a NodeList as opposed to an element (without jQuery)?

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("ul>li");
Velocity(elements, { ... }, { ... });
```

It would make for cleaner code than:

```
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    Velocity(elements[i], { ... }, { ... });
}
```

And, who knows, some <s>weird</s> magical performance gain? :)

Comment: According to [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/09/animating-without-jquery/#working-without-jquery), written by the author of the plugin, your code that passes a querySelectorAll NodeList into Velocity should work.

Comment: I guess I should just have tried it :). If you ANSWER the question, I'll mark it as accepted.